# Does iPhone 5 have a terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash, iphone, command-line

I'm new to iPhones and Mac, but I pretty ok with Linux. I think I could solve some of my networking issues, if I could just get into a bash shell, but I haven't been able to locate a shell.

Is there a default shell for iPhone 5? if so, where is it?

If not, is there a preferable terminal emulator in the App Store?

Comment: Also note that the OS is not Linux and networking etc will differ even if you could get access to it

Comment: yes, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iPhone does have a shell, bash to be specific, but you can't access the shell without jailbreaking, and any 'shell' app from the App Store won't have the ability to interact with the device in any reasonable manner necessary for fixing network problems.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not one that would be publicly accessible. You'd have to jailbreak your phone, at which point support for applications would not be covered. All app store applications run in protected sandbox mode purposefully to limit this type of interaction with the device.

(edit to clarify that the phone does have bash but not accessible to the everyman)

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted down, when it was a correct answer and also the first posted?